# Appcelerator - Add picker rows at runtime on Android

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to add rows into my picker depending on the user selection before, so I add the rows at runtime. On iOS the picker is refreshed and all works well but in Android nothing happens. I tried a lot of options but I can't do it.

This is my code:

**index.xml**

```
...
<TableViewRow id="row_seccion" layout="vertical">
       <Label id="label_seccion" class="textField_label">CATEGORÍA</Label>
       <Widget src="es.epi.comboBox2" class="selectField" id="seccion"  onChange='comboBoxClick'platform='android'></Widget>
</TableViewRow>

<TableViewRow id="row_subseccion" layout="vertical">
          <Label id="label_subseccion" class="textField_label">SUBCATEGORÍA</Label>
          <View id="subseccion" platform='android'></View>
</TableViewRow>
...
```

**index.js**

```
function comboBoxClick(e){
    Ti.API.debug("comboBoxClick " + e.value);
    if(e.value != -1) rellenarSubsecciones(e.value);
}

function rellenarSubsecciones(value){

       picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
            useSpinner: 'false',
            height: 50,
            left: 10,
            right: 10
        });

        Ti.API.debug("Subsecciones: " + subsecciones.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < subsecciones.length; i++)
        {
            var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow(subsecciones[i]);
            row.font = {fontFamily: Alloy.Estilos.fuentes.normal, fontSize: "18dp"};
            row.color = "#222222";
            row.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
            picker.add(row);
        }

        $.row_subseccion.add(picker);
}
```

I only need to refresh one view, but in Android seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use "useSpinner: true," in picker?

Comment: Nothing, the same that with false. Nothing appear.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation on Ti.UI.Picker.add()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-method-add) says *Once you use this method to add rows and columns to a picker, you cannot remove or manipulate them.*

I'm not sure if this **could** be done, but you might want to do a Feature Request [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org). Check if it has already been requested before you create a new ticket. Refer to this question and also link back to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: I'm putting the rows before I add the picker. I don't manipulate the rows.

Comment: Mmm, you're right. Well, could you then create a JIRA ticket to report this bug and include a simple test case?